# Undefined variable $statistic_teachers

Tags: laravel

I was trying to pass data to my view, but don't why there is a error

my blade which I want to pass data there

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">              
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('StatistikAnsicht') }}</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <table id="statisticforteacher" class="table-responsive" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <th>FrageTitel</th>
                            <th>Kapitel</th>
                            <th>RichtigeRate</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($statistic_teachers as $value)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$value -> question_title}}</td>
                                <td>{{$value -> chapters_id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$value -> correct_rate}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach                   
                        </tbody>                                           
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and my controller, and use a connection with model to pass data

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\StatisticTeacher;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StatisticTeacherController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function statisticteacher(){
        $statistic_teachers = StatisticTeacher::all();
        return view('statisticsA',compact('statistic_teachers'));
    }
}
```

and this is my route, I think it isn't about my route, when I didn't pass data to the view, everythink works.

```
Route::get('/author_views.statisticsA', 'PagesController@getStatisticsAdmin')->name('statisticsA')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/statisticsA', 'StatisticTeacherController@statisticteacher');
```

and this is model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StatisticTeacher extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','question_title','chapters_id','correct_answer','wrong_ansers','correct_rate'
    ]; 
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

I think  everything is ok, can not find such a syntax error, but it still doesn't work
can anyone help?

by the way this is stack trace
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWdyW.png)

Comment: share model  StatisticTeacher

Comment: Is that the right view that's being returned ? `resources/views/statisticsA.blade.php` ?
Make sure it has the right syntax(capital letters too)

Comment: can you pass the full error log?

Comment: try the variable `$statisticTeachers` with capital T without underscore

Comment: $statisticTeachers throw also the same error

Comment: What URL are you on when this error is triggered? Do both the `getStatisticsAdmin` and `statisticteacher` methods return the same view (`statisticsA.blade.php`)? Do you define and pass `$statistic_teachers` in both? Please provide more information.

Comment: ah, I see, I have already a controller, I don't need to make other controller just need one

Comment: Have you tried using vanilla declaration like this `return view('statisticsA', ['statistic_teachers' => $statistic_teachers]);`

Answer (score -1):

Please try below approach.

```php
<?php

class StatisticTeacherController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function statisticteacher(){
        $statistic_teachers = StatisticTeacher::all();
        return view('statisticsA',['statistic_teachers' => $statistic_teachers]);
    }
}
```

Check on which line in your blade file is throwing error. Compiled vies are stored inside `storage\framework\views` directory.